# how to fix too many variables in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm trying to create stacks of cards in my Flutter project. Each card contains different data/information and when I try visualize with a dummy data, I have to use a lot of variables which is pretty much repeating variable name for each card. Is there aways to make a reusable card component in flutter so that I can make it clear and simple because when I use real data in the future, I might have more than 2 cards in a group and they will also have different data. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

```
class MyConstructor {


MyConstructor({this.jonathan1,this.jonathan2,this.jonathan3});
}


class StackedCardsState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<MyConstructor> cards = [
    MyConstructor(h1: "Hello", h2: "hello3")
  ];

/////
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Text(MyConstructor.hey, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        Text(MyConstructor.hey),
                        Text(MyConstructor.hey, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[500]),),
                        VerticalDivider(color: Colors.blue),
                      ])),
```

Comment: Rather than using many variables in the `App` object for storing card data, you can store all data related directly to individual cards as a `Card` object and store `Card`s in the `App`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Hi..thank you for the comments but can you please show me how to do that?. I'm kinda stuck right now so I'll be appreciated if you can show me how so that I can follow along. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is first of all rather simple, you are violating the DRY concept (Don't repeat yourself, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself ).

As soon as you start copy pasting code take a moment and think about your code and how you can abstract it into a reusable component.

Another big issue that I think you are lacking is variable naming. It is a very very important part of writing code. Might seem trivial but it will be very hard to understand what a variable named `cardOne1` and `cardTwo2` actually mean. What is the purpose of that variable? What does it do?

Now with that said I understand your app has something to do with car sales but other than that I'm not really sure what I'm looking at. There for I will have a harder time finding a good variable for this code but here is an example.

So lets break down the contents in the card to a single reusable widget, we can also make a data class (or model) for storing the data that we then give to the widget.

```
//car_details.dart

class CarDetails {
  String title;
  String diffNumber;
  String diffPercent;
  Color colorIndicator;

  CarDetails({
    this.title,
    this.diffNumber,
    this.diffPercent,
    this.colorIndicator,
  });
}
```

```
//car_card_details.dart
class CarCardDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final double padding;
  final CarDetails carDetails;

  CarCardDetails({
    this.carDetails,
    this.padding = 15,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        carDetails.colorIndicator != null
            ? Container(
                color: carDetails.colorIndicator,
                height: 60,
                width: 2,
              )
            : Container(),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(carDetails.title),
              Text(carDetails.diffNumber),
              Text(carDetails.diffPercent),
              VerticalDivider(color: Colors.blue),
            ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

To use this component we make a CarCard Widget that takes a title and a list of CarDetails like so:

```
// car_card.dart
class CarCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<CarDetails> carDetails;

  CarCard({this.title, this.carDetails});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> detailRow = List();

    if (carDetails != null) {
      carDetails.forEach((element) {
        detailRow.add(CarCardDetails(
          top: element.title,
          middle: element.diffNumber,
          bottom: element.diffPercent,
          lineColor: element.colorIndicator,
        ));
      });
    }

    return Container(
      //height: 150, //I would not hardcode the height, let the childrent expand the widget instead
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Card(
          elevation: 8.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            child: Column(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(children: [
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.favorite)
                ]),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.black),
              Row(children: detailRow),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And instead of saving all the variables you had in app we can now make them into a list of CarDetails where each element contains the strings.

```
// some other widget

...

  List<CarDetails> carDetails = [
    CarDetails(
      title: "2 hrs ago",
      diffNumber: "+/ TRACK",
      diffPercent: "% to DBJ",
    ),
    CarDetails(
      title: "CHEVEROLET",
      diffNumber: "-2706",
      diffPercent: "42.2%",
      colorIndicator: Colors.red,
    ),
    CarDetails(
      title: "BUICK",
      diffNumber: "+300",
      diffPercent: "50%",
      colorIndicator: Colors.green,
    ),
    CarDetails(
      title: "GMC",
      diffNumber: "-712",
      diffPercent: "52.1%",
      colorIndicator: Colors.black26,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarCard(
        title: "US Daily Retail Delieveries by Brand", 
        carDetails: carDetails,
    );
  }

...
```

This can of course be abstracted even further with the groups of cards etc, etc. But I hope you get the idea.

This is an example of how you could do it, with that said I do not know what data you are intending to use and how you want to structure it. So consider this a starting point and take it from there. :)